# Unknown type name 'ESTBeaconRegion'; did you mean 'CLBeaconRegion'?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ibeacon, estimote

**Isssue 1:**

I'm following [this estimote tutorial](http://estimote.com/api/getting-started/create-your-own-app.html) to create my own Estimote app. However this error appeared:

> Unknown type name 'ESTBeaconRegion'; did you mean 'CLBeaconRegion'?

How to solve it?

I've included the header and also the delegate

```
#import <EstimoteSDK/EstimoteSDK.h>

@interface AppDelegate () <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,ESTBeaconManagerDelegate>
```

This is my podFile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'Tabster' do
pod 'EstimoteSDK', '3.1.0'
end
```

**Issue 2:**
Why is the framework highlighted in red?

[image]

**Update: (trying the Example app suggested by Juan Gonzalez)** 
[image]

Comment: Hi Mustafa Ibrahim, I've already included " #import <EstimoteSDK/EstimoteSDK.h>" and " #import "AppDelegate.h" "in the AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: The main focus of this question is the EstimoteSDK, it does not have anything to do with appdelegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use an "old app" with the new estimote SDK 3.0, i suggest you to go read the migration guide at this adress :

https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/blob/master/SDK_3_0_MIGRATION_GUIDE.md

ESTBeaconManager

ESTBeaconManager class remains, but with narrowed functionality. In the current form it is responsible for ranging and monitoring iBeacon devices as well as advertising as iBeacon. It mainly covers CoreLocation functionality but with useful helpers including preventUnknownUpdateCount, avoidUnknownStateBeacons and returnAllRangedBeaconsAtOnce (Already available in previous versions of Estimote SDK).

Delegate methods works with CLBeacon objects (instead of ESTBeacon) and CLBeaconRegion (instead of ESTBeaconRegion). Let's use ranging delegate as example:

SDK 2.4 syntax:

```
- (void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
      didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
             inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
{
    if (beacons.count > 0)
    {
        ESTBeacon *firstBeacon = [beacons objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

SDK 3.0 syntax:

```
- (void)beaconManager:(id)manager
      didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
             inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    if (beacons.count > 0)
    {
        CLBeacon *firstBeacon = [beacons objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: I'm following the outdated tutorial on the estimote website. Thx for providing the comparison between sdk3.0 and 2.4

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue using Estimote SDK library. For an unknown reason, if you try to include SDK library in a new Xcode project it doesn't seems to load it. Even if you use CoreLocation and CoreBluetooth headers.

I suggest you to use the sample code in order to have a project including libaries and then start to modify it.

Comment: Which sample code are you suggesting? I've tried to include this code in the "@property(nonatomic, strong) ESTBeaconRegion *beaconRegion;"   "Examples" app for "beacons" https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK. But it does not work as well... I've added the error screenshot in my question above.

Comment: The "Examples" app is using CLLocation instead of ESTBeaconRegion though.

Comment: That's right, use the Examples/beacons objective C project and modify it. In this case I used the Proximity sample code, remember to set your credentials in the app delegate, so you can start using your beacons registered in Estimote Cloud.

Comment: Yes will do it later, my estimote is still with the courier. [ESTCloudManager setupAppID:nil andAppToken:nil]; What's the advantage of using their SDK instead of using CoreLocation? Cause I can basically replace ESTBeaconManager with CLLocationManager and ESTBeaconRegion  with CLLocation

Comment: Well, I suggest to use their sample code to get Estimote SDK working well.   Both CoreLocation and CoreBluetooth are required from scratch or using sample code. If you want to make a general beacon app (not Estimote) then you should use CLLocationManager and CLLocation.

Answer (score 0):

Download code from [here](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK) and don't try to export it from pod file instead of that you can directly use Example xcode project exported from  iOS-SDK zip file you downloaded. Try it once if you are getting same problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

from heypiotr, "In SDK 3.0 we switched from ESTBeaconRegion to CLBeaconRegion, this tutorial you're doing wasn't yet updated to reflect that. It's easy though: just change all your ESTBeaconRegion occurrences to CLBeaconRegion. And while you're at it, we also changed ESTBeacon to CLBeacon, so you may want to replace these as well." That explains everything. Thx guys!